# How many words are there in the words.txt file that have the vowels a e i o u in order?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, return, cpu-word

The function `uses` will always return True. If I do it correctly, there will only be 12 words.

How do I make it so `uses` will return False?

```
def count_vowels():
    fin = open ('words.txt')
    count = 0
    vowels = ['aeiou']
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        if uses(word, vowels):
            count = count + 1
            print "There are", count ," words with a vowel."

def uses(word, vowels):
    for vowels in word:
        if vowels in vowels:
            return True
    return False

def count_words():                                
    fin = open ('words.txt')
    vowels = ['aeiou']
    for line in fin:
            word = line.strip()
            if uses(word, vowels):
                print word

count_vowels()
count_words()

#This is what returns in the shell when I run my code:

>>>There are 1 words with a vowel.
There are 2 words with a vowel.
There are 3 words with a vowel.
There are 4 words with a vowel.
There are 5 words with a vowel.
....
#and so on...

# However, if I use the following code to replace the middle function in my original code:

def uses(word, vowels):
    found = ''
    for l in word:
        if l not in found:
            if l in vowels:
                found += l
        else:
            return False
    return found == vowels

# When I run the code the shell returns this:

>>>
>>>
```

Comment: What is the current result? Also, can you give us a sample of the input?

Comment: Does `'atetitotu'` counts as Ordered?

Comment: why do you have the vowels in a list all as one string?

Comment: It could be because you're removing letters from `vowels` but never putting them back in for the next word...

Comment: Does the order of vowels in a word has to be `aeiou`?

Comment: The current result kept printing:

"There are", #," words with a vowel." over 1000 times

Comment: I updated the middle function. The order of vowels needs to be 'aeiou'.

I want to print the result 12 times of:

"There are # words with a vowel" as stated in the top function.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `all` function! Let the magic works:

```
def uses(word, vowels):
    return all(letter in word for letter in vowels)
```

Demo:

```
>>> s = 'aieou cdeaiou fgeaihou test doesnt work'
>>> for i in s.split():
    print (uses(i, 'aiueo'))


True
True
True
False
False
False
```

With this, you pass `vowels` as a string of `"aiueo"` instead of `['aiueo']`.

But, if you want the vowels to be found in order, use this:

```
def uses(word, vowels):
    found = ''
    for l in word:
        if l not in found:
            if l in vowels:
                found += l
        else:
            return False
    return found == vowels
```

Here, kind of dissapointing, but i'll just give you the full fixed code:

```
def count_vowels():               
    with open('words.txt') as fin:
        count = 0
        vowels = 'aeiou'
        for line in fin:
            words = line.split()
            for word in words:
                if uses(word, vowels):
                    count = count + 1
                    print "There are", count ," words with a vowel."

def uses(word, vowels):
    return all(letter in word for letter in vowels)

def count_words():                                
    with open('words.txt') as fin:
        vowels = 'aeiou'
        for line in fin:
                words = line.split()
                for word in words:
                    if uses(word, vowels):
                        print word

count_vowels()
count_words()
```

Comment: **vowels `a e i o u` in order?**

Comment: Not necessarily? What do you mean?

Comment: Ah i see.. wait a second, the OP hasn't cleared that just yet.

Comment: I'm a bit rushed i guess :)

Comment: It's supposed to return this 12 times:

"There are", count ," words with a vowel."

Comment: Oh, that's unrelated with the question. I think you should change `line.strip` to `line.split()` since it's most probably what you needed. That should fix it.

Comment: And the same in `count_words`

Comment: When I put in your code, for the middle and change line.strip() to line.split(), it still doesn't work. It returns:
>>>
>>>

Is there anything else I need to change to make it print out 12 times?

Comment: Please post the sample input, it's hard to understand what are you doing without that.

Comment: I added it to my original question/post at the top. I need it to print out 12 times. So it should say: "There are 12 words with a vowel." Does that make sense?

Comment: The input. We need the input.

Comment: Post a part of your file here, just as an example.

Comment: def uses(word, vowels):
    for vowels in word:
        if vowels in vowels:
            return True
    return False

Comment: Not your script.. Your file! The `word.txt` is that not clear enough?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. aa
aah 
aahed 
aahing 
aahs 
aal 
aalii 
aaliis 
aals

Comment: But none of your input has all of the vowels in it. What do you actually want?

Comment: And there is more than 100,000 words in there ranging from the letter 'a' to letter 'z'

Comment: Do you want to check if there is a vowel inside a word or not?

Comment: Like I said there is more than 100,000 words in there. So there are probably words that have all the vowels in them.

Comment: And? You know for sure that there is 12 words with all the vowels?

Comment: I contacted my professor and that was what he told me as a hint.

Comment: Okay.. Now what is the result of my two solutions?

Comment: I know for sure that the top and bottom functions are correct, just the middle one I am having problems with.

Comment: If I replace your bottom solution with my original middle function from the top, I get a return with these two symbols in the shell: ">>> >>>" so nothing prints out.

Comment: If I keep my original middle function, it prints out numerous times: "There are", #," words with a vowel." well over 1000 times.

Comment: So, you have make sure that in `count_vowels`, `vowels` is `'aeiou'`, not `['aeiou']`?

Comment: Does having brackets around the string make a difference?

Comment: MAKES A HUGE DIFFERENCE

Comment: Okay. So, I got rid of those, and I put in your second solution, but I'm still getting a return of ">>> >>>" in the shell.

Comment: By using brackets, you make it a list, not a string.

Comment: Okay, I put in your updated answer, but why is it still returning ">>> >>>" is it supposed to do that?

Comment: Ahh you have a problem with the loop. `word` is a list of words, not lines. Try my updated answer.

Comment: It works, but I am getting the same result as I did before with: "There are", #," words with a vowel." more than 1000 times.

Comment: Where are you running the script?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm in Python. I go to 'RUN' - 'Run Module' and it prints out the result in the Python shell.

Comment: What software are you using again?

Comment: Actually never mind. I think there are 598 words. Because it printed out: "There are 598 words with a vowel" and printed words containing all the vowels in them. Such as: aboideau aboideaus aboideaux aboiteau aboiteaus aboiteaux abstemious abstemiously accentuation

Comment: You mean the version of Python? I'm using 2.7.5

Comment: Now, replace your `uses` function with the second one i provided.

Comment: I got 5 words: abstemious abstemiously arsenious facetious facetiously

Comment: So it is printing out the vowels in order like I need them to.

Comment: Could be either. The point is that your function works, so please do accept the answer.

Comment: I will. I do appreciate your help throughout all of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for only words with all of the letters `aeiou` in that order (but possibly with other letters in between), you need to be checking against the first vowel until you find it, then against the second vowel, then the third, until you've found them all (or reached the end of the word). Here's some code that does that:

```
def uses(word, vowels)
    vowel_index = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter == vowels[vowel_index]:
            vowel_index += 1
            if vowel_index == len(vowels):
                return True
    return False
```

Rather than deleting the vowels as they're found, I simply keep an integer index that tells me which vowel I'm testing against at the moment.

You'll want to call this with a subscriptable value for `vowels`, either a list with one-character strings as its contents, or a single string with all the vowels in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I got that right, I would implement a `uses`-function like this:

```
def uses(word, vowels):
    # remove every letter, that's not a vowel, make the word lower case
    reduced_word = filter( lambda character: character in vowels, word.lower() )
    # check, whether the vowels are in order
    return vowels in reduced_word

vowels = "aeiou"

test_words = [ "atetitotu", "Atetitotu", "Haemodiutory", "FgeAihou" ]

for word in test_words: print word, uses(word, vowels)
```

**Output:**

```
atetitotu True
Atetitotu True
Haemodiutory False
FgeAihou False
```

But if you want to find all those words of a file, I will recommend `re`-module:

```
import re
file_content = open('file.txt').read()
vowels = "aeiou"
# the pattern starts with word boundary and there can be any kind of letters at the beginning
pattern = r"\b\w*"
# than between every vowel there can be any letter, except of a vowel
pattern += (r"[^%s]*?" % vowels ).join(vowels)
# and then, after the last vowel there can be any letter before the word ends
pattern += r"\w*\b"
# here the result: pattern = r"\b\w*a[^aeiou]*?e[^aeiou]*?i[^aeiou]*?o[^aeiou]*?u\w*\b"
# now we look for this pattern all over the file, ignoring case
re.findall(pattern, file_content, flags = re.I)
```

The Output would be like this

```
['atetitotu', 'Atetitotu']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def uses_only(wrd_trnsv, str_chars):
    for chr_trnsv in wrd_trnsv:
        if chr_trnsv not in str_chars:
            return False
    return True

wrd_list = open('C:\\Temp\\Complete_Words_list.txt')
def uses_all_txt(wrd_list, req_str_chrs):
    count = 0
    for each_wrd in wrd_list :
        if uses_only(req_str_chrs,each_wrd):
            count = count + 1
     return count
```

Answer (score -1):

like @void said, use `re` module

```
import re
s = 'hello world'
words = re.findall(r'\w+', s)
print 'words'''
```